# Create line graph comparing pre and post median values of two groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I have a dataframe with 2 cond, and 2 time points within each cond (pre and post).  I am looking to create a line graph showing the pre and post MEDIAN values from the sc column from a group of subjects on both conds.  I would also like there to be a line connecting the pre and post values on each cond.  ie. Pre ------ Post for cond #1, and Pre ----- Post for cond #2.

Data:

```
id    cond    time    sc
1      1       0      400
2      1       0      370
1      1       1      300
2      1       1      302
1      2       0      402
2      2       0      380
1      2       1      220
2      2       1      203
```

This is just a sample of the data.  There are 11 subjects (id 1:11) in my data set for each condition at each time point.  This is the best code I have so far:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = time, y = sc, group = cond, color = factor(cond))) +
geom_line() +
geom_point() +
facet_wrap(~cond) +
ylab("Switch Cost")
```

Right now this code gives me all the points from each condition (cond) and not just one point showing the median values.  Been searching online for quite a few hours today but can't find an example similar to what I'm trying to create.

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using?  What have you tried so far?   What are the issues you encountered?

Comment: Just added those points.  Sorry for the omission.

Comment: You're generally better off if you manipulate your data (i.e., calculate pre and post medians by group), then plot it. Trying to do both at once sometimes works but is usually the complicated way to do things. There are many many questions on how to calculate groupwise statistics (means, medians, anything).

Comment: Very true Gregor.  I am very, very new to R, and computer programming in general, so I'm trying to learn as much as I can about the language.  I wasn't sure which was easier in this case, so I decided to ask the community that knows!  I'm starting to realize that most of the time, prep work is 99% of the battle though!!

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
d1 <- "id    cond    time    sc
1      1       0      400
2      1       0      370
1      1       1      300
2      1       1      302
1      2       0      402
2      2       0      380
1      2       1      220
2      2       1      203"
library("data.table")
d1 <- data.table(read.table(text=d1, header = TRUE))
d1[, "median" := median(sc), by=list(cond, time)]
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(d1, aes(x=time, y=median, color=factor(cond))) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

giving:

[image]

I find `data.table` is the easiest approach for this type of 'group-by'/ 'summarize' problem, but there are many others.

Also, careful about calling things `df` as this overwrites `stats::df()`.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla R, you would use `aggregate` for the same functionality as @dardisco's `data.tables` solution.

```
d1 <- ... as above ...
d2 <- read.table(text=d1, header=T)
d3 <- aggregate(sc ~ time + cond, d2, median)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(d3) + geom_line(aes(x=time, y=sc, color=factor(cond))
```